# Clojure XML zipper walk and prune

Tags: xml, clojure, tree, truncate, zipper

I am walking a html/xml data structure. I walk through it using `clojure.zip`. Once I find a node at which I want to `cut` (prune), I cannot find a way to remove all children and right nodes.

**Example:**

Let's say I have this tree (that represents html):

```
(def tree [:p "F"
           [:p "G" [:p "I" [:p "H"]]]
           [:p "B"
            [:p
             "D"
             [:p "E"]
             [:p "C"]]
            [:p "A"]]])
```

I parse it, `xml-zip` it, and at some point while walking I end up in node "D", where I want to cut. I now need to return the root without "E", "C" (children) and "D". Those are all the nodes that are not visited already when using `next` at this point.

How would I remove these nodes?

**Note:** if this is not feasible, I would also welcome an approach that copies the zipper up to the `cut` point.

**Example data:** This is the parsed data that I have for the above tree, on which I call `xml-zip`:

```
{:tag :html, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :head, :attrs nil, :content nil} {:tag :body, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["F"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["G"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["I"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["H"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content nil} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content nil} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["B"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["D"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["E"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["C"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content nil} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["A"]} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content nil} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content nil}]}]}
```

And I start walking through it like so to get the content:

```
(-> parsed (z/xml-zip)
           (z/down) ;head
           (z/right) ; body
           (z/down) ; content
           )
```

**Another example:**

the following string: `"<article><h1><img href=\"some-url\"></img> some-text <b>in bold</b></h1><ul><li> AA </li> <li>BB</li></ul></article>"`
  will give me the following map:

```
[{:tag :html, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :head, :attrs nil, :content nil} {:tag :body, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :article, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :h1, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :img, :attrs {:href "some-url"}, :content nil} " some-text " {:tag :b, :attrs nil, :content ["in bold"]}]} {:tag :ul, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :li, :attrs nil, :content [" AA "]} " " {:tag :li, :attrs nil, :content ["BB"]}]}]}]}]} nil]
```

when cutting at "some-text" it should ultimately result in the string  `<article><h1><img href=\"some-url\"></img> some-text</h1></article>`

Comment: You can use https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip/remove for removing a node and the subtree associated with it.

Comment: @Grav it removes the node, but does not seem to remove the subtree associated with it.

Comment: (and even if it did, in my example A is not part of the subtree of D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs of all, i would rephrase your task the following way:

The goal is to find some node, and then remove it and everything to the right of it from it's *parent*.

Stated this way, the `cut` function can be easily implemented with the help of `clojure.zip/edit` for parent:

```
(defn cut [loc]
  (when-let [parent (z/up loc)]
    (z/edit parent #(z/make-node loc % (z/lefts loc)))))
```

so, as it was said above, we edit the parent of the `loc`, making the new node of it, keeping only the children to the left of the `loc`.

notice, that there is the `when-let` macro there, to avoid the null pointer exception if the passed location doesn't have parent (meaning it is the root of the zipper)

Now the test:

let's try to delete the `p` containing `["I"]`:

```
user> (-> html
          z/xml-zip
          z/down
          z/right
          z/down
          z/right
          z/right
          z/node)
;; {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["I"]}

user> (-> html
          z/xml-zip
          z/down
          z/right
          z/down
          z/right
          z/right
          cut
          z/root)
;;{:tag :html, :attrs nil, 
;; :content [{:tag :head, :attrs nil, :content nil} 
;;           {:tag :body, :attrs nil, 
;;            :content [{:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["F"]} 
;;                      {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ["G"]}]}]}
```

as expected: everything to the right from (and including) `I` was removed from the body.

**update**

according to the update, you want to remove all the nodes in the tree *after the target one*. This is a little bit more tricky, since it requires changing all the node's parents up to the root. In this case the `cut` function could look like this:

```
(defn cut [loc]
  (loop [loc loc]
    (if-let [parent (z/up loc)]
      (recur
       (z/replace parent
                  (z/make-node loc
                               (z/node parent)
                               (drop-last (count (z/rights loc))
                                          (z/children parent)))))
      (z/node loc))))
```

test:

```
user> (-> h2 
          z/xml-zip 
          z/down 
          z/right 
          z/down 
          z/down 
          z/down 
          z/right 
          cut)

;;{:tag :html, :attrs nil, 
;; :content [{:tag :head, :attrs nil, :content nil} 
;;           {:tag :body, :attrs nil, 
;;            :content [{:tag :article, :attrs nil, 
;;                       :content [{:tag :h1, :attrs nil, 
;;                                  :content [{:tag :img, :attrs {:href "some-url"}, :content nil} " some-text "]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: I will have a closer look this evening but that looks good, thanks!

Comment: I tried it on another example (in my edited question), it does not seem to work: ```
  (-> html zip/zml-zip
      zip/down
      zip/right
      zip/down
      zip/down
      zip/down
      zip/right
      cut
      zip/root) ;; AA and BB are still there```

Comment: but `AA` and `BB` are not the children of the `some-text`'s parent node (`h1`), they are the children of the parent's sibling.

Comment: Or did you mean that you had to remove all the nodes in all the parents, following the target one ? meaning that the node before the one being cut should be the last one in the resulting tree?

Comment: and do you have to remove the target item itself? or it should be kept in the result?

Comment: I basically have to do it as if I was truncating html in reading order. So I have to keep the nodes that I have visited and remove the others (this is what I just came up with). But this approach is not very efficient.

Comment: Seems to work, could you expand a bit on the `drop-last` part ?

Comment: the drop-last part is about dropping all the children to the right of the current `loc`. At this point we know about all the elements to the right (thanks to `z/rights`), so we replace the loc's parent with exactly the same, but removing all the unneeded children.